# TypeError: Expected string, got list containing Tensors of type '_Message' instead

Tags: python, tensorflow

Python 3.6 on windows 7
(Jupyter Notebook)

I'm trying to load label csv file. but it's not working properly.
The csv file has been created already. (1 column, 570 rows)

I'v been googled to debug this problem, but i can't find
the exact case like this.

finally, I wanna train jpg files with this label file.

in **model.py**

```
imagename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(images, shuffle=False)
labelname_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer([csv_label], shuffle=False)

# print(type(labelname_queue))

image_reader = tf.WholeFileReader()
key_img, raw_img = image_reader.read(imagename_queue)

csv_reader = tf.TextLineReader()
key_txt, raw_txt = csv_reader.read(labelname_queue)

jpg_image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(raw_img)
csv_label = tf.decode_csv(raw_txt, record_defaults=[[0]])

jpg_image = tf.reduce_mean(jpg_image, axis=2)
jpg_image = tf.reshape(jpg_image, [W_img, H_img, 1])
```

I got this error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-6c24000e9977> in <module>()
      1 imagename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(images, shuffle=False)
----> 2 labelname_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer([csv_label], shuffle=False)
      3 
      4 # print(type(labelname_queue))
      5 

C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\input.py in string_input_producer(string_tensor, num_epochs, shuffle, seed, capacity, shared_name, name, cancel_op)
    218 
    219   with ops.name_scope(name, "input_producer", [string_tensor]) as name:
--> 220     string_tensor = ops.convert_to_tensor(string_tensor, dtype=dtypes.string)
    221     with ops.control_dependencies([
    222         control_flow_ops.Assert(

C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py in convert_to_tensor(value, dtype, name, preferred_dtype)
    609       name=name,
    610       preferred_dtype=preferred_dtype,
--> 611       as_ref=False)
    612 
    613 

C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py in internal_convert_to_tensor(value, dtype, name, as_ref, preferred_dtype)
    674 
    675         if ret is None:
--> 676           ret = conversion_func(value, dtype=dtype, name=name, as_ref=as_ref)
    677 
    678         if ret is NotImplemented:

C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\constant_op.py in _constant_tensor_conversion_function(v, dtype, name, as_ref)
    119                                          as_ref=False):
    120   _ = as_ref
--> 121   return constant(v, dtype=dtype, name=name)
    122 
    123 

C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\constant_op.py in constant(value, dtype, shape, name, verify_shape)
    100   tensor_value = attr_value_pb2.AttrValue()
    101   tensor_value.tensor.CopyFrom(
--> 102       tensor_util.make_tensor_proto(value, dtype=dtype, shape=shape, verify_shape=verify_shape))
    103   dtype_value = attr_value_pb2.AttrValue(type=tensor_value.tensor.dtype)
    104   const_tensor = g.create_op(

C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\tensor_util.py in make_tensor_proto(values, dtype, shape, verify_shape)
    374       nparray = np.empty(shape, dtype=np_dt)
    375     else:
--> 376       _AssertCompatible(values, dtype)
    377       nparray = np.array(values, dtype=np_dt)
    378       # check to them.

C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\tensor_util.py in _AssertCompatible(values, dtype)
    300     else:
    301       raise TypeError("Expected %s, got %s of type '%s' instead." %
--> 302                       (dtype.name, repr(mismatch), type(mismatch).__name__))
    303 
    304 

TypeError: Expected string, got list containing Tensors of type '_Message' instead.
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: How is `csv_label` defined?

Comment: @mrry  it's a path of the file  csv_label = "D:/DLPrj/inception/tensorflow/work/letter/label_csv/label.csv"